# how does one support pagination using bigtable Go client?

Tags: go, pagination, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I store time series data in bigtable with a rowKey of userId#timestamp. Given query parameters of (userId, startTime, endTime) how can I support pagination i.e return 'limit' records starting from 'offset' ?

note that userId#startTime rowKey may not exist in bigtable but there will some datapoints before and after startTime/EndTime. Bigtable Go client seems to support ReadRows with a prefixRange argument. I could use a prefixRange of userId and 'seek' to the startTime as I iterate using ReadRows but this seems very inefficient if starTime/endTime is way in the past. is there a better way ??

Comment: This post may have what you're looking for, take a look and let me know it works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691823/bigtable-node-client-how-to-set-read-offset-for-pagination

Comment: thank you maxim but bigtable Go client doesn't have the readStream interface like the Node client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start a [ReadRows](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable#Table.ReadRows) operation from `userId#startTime` to `userId#endTime` with a [NewRange](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable#NewRange) and set a limit on the number of rows returned with a [LimitRows](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable#LimitRows) read option.

```
err = tbl.ReadRows(ctx, NewRange("<userId>#<startTime>", "<userId>#<endTime>"), func(r Row) bool {
    fmt.Println("Got a row")
    return true
}, LimitRows(100))
```