# BigTable - Drop/Skip the first N Rows

Tags: python, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Is it possible to drop/skip the first N Rows in BigTable?

I'm trying to perform pagination for an API endpoint with BigTable outputs.

The closest filter is: `CellsRowOffsetFilter` ([BigTable Documentation)](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/row-filters.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row_filters.CellsRowOffsetFilter)

However, this filter only skips the N versions of the cell, and not the output row.

It's possible to drop the first N rows using iterators, but this will consume BigTable's read throughput, which doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately there's currently no support for this. Can you describe your use case for this feature in a bit more detail? I may be able to provide an alternative, and if not we'll consider it a feature request!

Comment: @DouglasMcErlean For example pagination, user wants only the first 100 rows, or the second 100 set of rows (excluding the first 100 rows). Is there an alternative to this? I could get just 100 rows (or a little bit more depending on the version on that row key, since I might get two or more writes on the same row key), and then instead of passing back a pagination row counter, I pass a timestamp?

Comment: Instead of passing back a pagination row counter, you could instead pass a pagination row key (the 100th row key that you saw), allowing you to start the next request from that row key instead of the initial one.

Comment: If pagination is what you need, Dan's suggestion is exactly what I'd recommend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach as discussed in the comments to your question, would be to read some number of rows using a row limit, then pass the row key of the last row in the response as the start_key for the next request.

See also [Bigtable node client: How to set read offset for pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691823/bigtable-node-client-how-to-set-read-offset-for-pagination).

Comment: This is the approach I ended up taking! Some credits to Douglas McErlean.